react component out of sync updating parent page
I have a component that is placed on a next.js page.  I have a button on the containing page and a summary field that shows the total of the selected rows that are within the component.  i pass and update function as props for both updating the total and updating the state of the button.  When the row selection changes in the component, i am calling the functions in the page to display the new total as well as check if the button should be enabled or disabled. it appears i have a sequencing of sync / async issue.  The total gets updated correctly based on the selected rows but the button update always seems to be one iteration behind. so when i select one row the button disables, but when i turn that row off (0 rows selected) the button then enables.  I have tried many different things include making the update totals function async so I am using an await to make sure the totals update before setting the button state but it has not helped.  Here are the relevant pieces of code.  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
displaying the button in the page
        {(openDisabled === true) && (
            <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="success"
            //startIcon={!isLoading ? <SaveAltIcon /> : null}
            style={{
                backgroundColor: addToBatchDisabled ? "grey" : "green",
                color: "white",
            }}
            type="submit"
            onClick={handleAddToBatch}
            disabled={addToBatchDisabled}
            >
                {isLoading ? (
                <CircularProgress color="secondary" size={20} />
                ) : (
                "Add Selected to Batch"
                )}
            </Button>
            )}

setting the opendisabled state in the page
 function updateSetAdd(buttonState){
    console.log ("update called ", batchChargesTotal, batchCreditsTotal);
    //setAddToBatchDisabled(buttonState)
    if ( +batchChargesTotal === 0 && +batchCreditsTotal === 0)
        setAddToBatchDisabled (true);
    else
        setAddToBatchDisabled (false);

setting the totals in the page
  const updateBatchCharges = useCallback(async(charges) =>  {
    setBatchChargesTotal ( (+charges) ); 
  })

  const updateBatchCredits = useCallback(async(credits) =>  {
    setBatchCreditsTotal ( (+credits) );
  })
  }

displaying the component on the page
        {credits.length > 0 && (
        <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
        <CreditsTable credits={credits} update={updateBatchCredits} setAdd={updateSetAdd} />
        </Box>
        )}

selecting the row and changing the values in the containing page.  select row is called by the onclick of the row of the mui table.
 const calcTotal = async () => {
    let tot = 0;
    rows.map((row) => {
        //console.log (row);
        if (row.checked) {
            tot = tot +(+row.amount);
            //console.log (row.amount, tot)
        }
    })
    setTotal (tot.toFixed(2));
    await props.update (tot.toFixed(2));
    //console.log ("t= ", tot)
    if (tot>0)
        props.setAdd(false);
    else
        props.setAdd(true);
  }

  const selectRow = (id) => {
    const copyRows = [...rows]
    copyRows[id].checked = !copyRows[id].checked
    setRows (copyRows);
    calcTotal();
  }

i would expect that the button state and the total value would be in sync and would update together given the calls and where they are made

This question is similar to: The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As above, the problem is that even though you can setAdd after calling update, since they are called in the same event loop, the call to setAdd will still have the old values of batchChargesTotal and  batchCreditsTotal. Thats because state changes aren't effected until a render cycle occurs, which is after the event loop is complete. The problem is a design issue. setAddToBatchDisabled  shouldnt even exist as a piece of state as its a computed value. Instead, calculate if batch should be disabled inside a useMemo with batchChargesTotal and batchCreditsTotal in its deps array.

The setAdd prop, the calls to that prop, and updateSetAdd in the parent can be removed entirely. As well as the useState() for addToBatchDisabled in the parent. Then simply const addToBatchDisabled = useMemo(() => +batchChargesTotal === 0 && +batchCreditsTotal === 0, [batchChargesTotal, batchCreditsTotal ]) in the parent. Now, it will "just happen" when the changes are applied via the update prop. It is a common error beginners make with react to model computed values as new state. Doing that opens a whole new surface area of bugs that shouldn't exist.

thank you for the help and good day
